# error 0x800B0100: The app package must be digitally signed for signature validation

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sideloading

I am trying to test an application by installing the application using WinAppDeployCmd.exe but i am receiving the following error:

Installing app...
Remote action failed. 0x800B0100
error 0x800B0100: The app package must be digitally signed for signature validation.

I have created to package through visual studio through the create for app store option.

Comment: is the phone registered as development phone?

Comment: Yes I can deploy it through visual studio I need to side load it to simulate an upgrade from the version that is currently on the store.